# How to create automated tests with Siri?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode8, siri

In new Xcode 8.3.1 was added Siri support in the iOS Simulator to improve automated testing. So my question is really simple. How? Has apple released some documentation regarding to this topic?